# Apex to get the name of the org edition?

Tags: apex, editions

Would like to detect which Salesforce Edition my Apex classes are running. I've been pouring over the documentation but so far haven't found the right class and method to retrieve this as a string.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query the `OrganizationType` field from the `Organization` object.

```
Organization org = [select OrganizationType from Organization];
```

Unlike most queries, you can assume that exactly one record exists for this query.

This field appears to be a pick list, so you can describe it to see all possible values.

Comment: Thank you - just what I was looking for!